# I try to create a process using 'fork'

Tags: c, linux

I'm start to studying the fork. while using the fork, I have some problems.
I'm trying to create a single parent process with two child
and two child trying to make each three grandchild.
When I run my code, unlike my expectations, so many child and grandchild come out.

Here my code:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, rev;

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if((rev=fork())<0) { printf("fork() error\n"); exit(-1); }
        else if(rev==0)
        {
            printf("child %d %d \n",getpid(),getppid());

            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if((rev=fork()) <0) { printf("fork() error\n"); exit(-1); }
                else if(rev == 0)
                {
                    printf("grandch %d %d \n",getppid(),getpid());
                    exit(0);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    printf("parent %d %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
    exit(0);
}
```

How can I correct this code?

Comment: Call `_exit(0)` at the end of each `else if (rev==0) {` branch or else the children will continue the forking loop.

Comment: @PSkocik: if you elaborate it a little it is the answer...

Answer (score 4):

One important **example** before using fork() statements :

```
//Calculate number of times hello is printed.
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Number of times hello printed is equal to number of process created. Total **Number of Processes = 2^n** where n is number of fork system calls. So here n = 3, 2^3 = 8.

```
fork ();   // Line 1
fork ();   // Line 2
fork ();   // Line 3

       L1       // There will be 1 child process 
    /     \     // created by line 1.
  L2      L2    // There will be 2 child processes
 /  \    /  \   //  created by line 2
L3  L3  L3  L3  // There will be 4 child processes 
                // created by line 3
```

> So if you are trying to make **two child process and then three grand
>   child** follow something of this sort:

What you should do is something like this for *two child processes*

```
if(fork()) # parent
    if(fork()) #parent
    else # child2
else #child1
```

After you create process , you should check the return value. If you don't , the second fork() will be executed by both the parent process and the child process, *so you have four processes.*

If you want to create **n child processes** , just :

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid) {  //means pid is non-zero value, i.e, pid>0
        continue;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        printf("fork error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The section of code that runs for the child processes doesn't exit.  As a result, they continue on to run more iterations of the outer loop which only the parent process is supposed to run, so they spawn more children.

You need to call `exit`, or better yet `_exit`, so that the children don't do that:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, rev;

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if((rev=fork())<0) { printf("fork() error\n"); exit(-1); }
        else if(rev==0)
        {
            printf("child %d %d \n",getpid(),getppid());

            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if((rev=fork()) <0) { printf("fork() error\n"); exit(-1); }
                else if(rev == 0)
                {
                    printf("grandch %d %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
                    _exit(0);
                }
            }

            sleep(1);      // stick around so the grandchild can print the parent pid
            _exit(0);      // exit the child
        }
    }
    printf("parent %d %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
    sleep(1);   // stick around so the child can print the parent pid
    exit(0);
}
```